# How to disable mongodb java driver's DefaultServerMonitor Thread

Tags: java, mongodb

I added apache metamodel into my project.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.metamodel</groupId>
    <artifactId>MetaModel-full</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

mongo-java-driver came as a dependency.

```
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.metamodel:MetaModel-mongodb-mongo3:jar:5.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.metamodel:MetaModel-mongodb-common:jar:5.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:jar:3.4.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.metamodel:MetaModel-mongodb-mongo2:jar:5.0.0:compile
```

Then I see some logs like.

```
2018-01-16 02:33:09.467  INFO 15417 --- [  restartedMain] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
2018-01-16 02:33:09.512 DEBUG 15417 --- [  restartedMain] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Updating cluster description to  {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]
2018-01-16 02:33:09.521 DEBUG 15417 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Closing connection connectionId{localValue:1}
2018-01-16 02:33:09.525  INFO 15417 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017

com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
        at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:63)
        at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:115)
        at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:113)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:57)
        at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:58)
        ... 3 common frames omitted

2018-01-16 02:33:09.527 DEBUG 15417 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Updating cluster description to  {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)}}]
```

When I dig source code of mongo-java-driver I see mongo-java-driver starts a Thread to monitor default mongodb server. I dont want to exclude mongodb driver but how can I disable com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor thread.

Answer (score 3):

After further search I realized that it is spring-boot autoconfiguration issue. My application is a spring-boot app. spring-boot auto config finds a mongos-java-driver jar in classpath and start-up mongo-drive.

Added `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {MongoAutoConfiguration.class})` and mongo-java-driver doesn't start anymore.

Comment: Please elaborate the solution a bit more. Where did you include the annotation